# How to find missed ids in my table?

Tags: database, postgresql

How to find missed ids in my table? for example right now ids are

```
1
3
8
```

my aim is find missed values

```
2
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.v from generate_series(1, (select max(id) from your_table))  s(v)
left join your_table
on s.v = your_table.id
WHERE your_table.id IS NULL
```

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is cleaner here, but ultimately it does the same thing. `SELECT s.v from generate_series(1, (select max(id) from your_table))  s(v) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE s.v = id )`

Comment: @EvanCarroll - for me personally, find values from "a" which are not in "b",  LEFT JOIN with IS NULL is more cleaner.

Comment: You're unique then. =) The `NOT EXISTS` is pretty semantic, and it's conditions are contained.

Comment: thank you, this works ! thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 1):

See [generate_series(start, stop)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) function. Just `LEFT JOIN` the series with your `id`s to get the missing ones.

Or use `EXCEPT` operator

```
SELECT
    generate_series(1, MAX(id)) AS id
FROM
    the_table
EXCEPT
SELECT
    id
FROM
    the_table
```

Answer (score 0):

For style reasons only, this also results in an anti-join ([like @Oto Shavadze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43430521/124486)). You can pick which style you like more. `NOT EXISTS` should be preferred where applicable because

1. it reduces the set, and `NOT EXISTS` is explicit in that. A left-join can have the effect of growing the set.
2. it's conditions are contained, there is no chance the `inner.id = outer.id` can drift away from the clause.
3. the inner table is not made available anywhere else in the query.

Here is an example,

```
SELECT s.v
FROM generate_series(1, (SELECT max(id) FROM yourTable))
  AS s(v)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM yourTable
  WHERE s.v = id
);
```